# How to get iid from selection_set() function in treeview?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, treeview

I'm attempting to get the iid of a row after the selection_set() function has been called to highlight a specific row in a treeview. Whenever I run tv.focus() after running a selection_set(), nothing gets returned. Here's an example:

```
tv4 = ttk.Treeview(window, height = 4)
tv4['columns']=('DOS', 'Encounter #', 'Encounter ID')

tv4.column('#0', width=0, stretch=NO)
tv4.column('DOS', anchor='w', width=100)
tv4.column('Encounter #', anchor='w', width=250)
tv4.column('Encounter ID', anchor='w', width=0, stretch = NO)



tv4.heading('#0', text='', anchor=CENTER)
tv4.heading('DOS', text='DOS', anchor='w')
tv4.heading('Encounter #', text="Encounter #", anchor='w')
tv4.heading('Encounter ID', text="Encounter ID", anchor='w')

tv4.insert(parent='', index=0, iid=0, text='', values=(i[0], i[1], i[2]))
tv4.insert(parent='', index=1, iid=1, text='', values=(i[0], i[1], i[2]))

tv4.selection_set('0') #Highlights row
tv4.focus() #Returns nothing
```

Is there anyway of capturing the iid in this scenario? Thank you!

(I don't want the user to click the row, I want it to be automatically captured after the set_selection() function).

Comment: You already know the iid is `'0'` since that's what you're passing to the function, why do you need it to be returned?

Comment: @BryanOakley Sorry. I should have been more clear. I have data being passed through that automatically calls selection_set on the appropriate row. There is also a different number of rows each time. Does that make sense? I need to call .focus to get the current iid for the current row.

Comment: So, the call to `selection_set` is in a different block of code that where you want the iid?  It's still a big unclear what you're asking since `selection_set` doesn't necessarily change the focus. The selection and the focus are two different things.

Comment: Use `tv4.selection()` instead of `tv4.focus()`.

Comment: @acw1668 This is really late, but this is what I was looking for! Thank you. If you make it an answer I'll gladly accept it.